# Ajax call will not work

Tags: php, ajax

I have this method that I want to run a php file using ajax and then reload the page.

```
function winA() 
{
var x = "<?php echo $id;?>"
$.ajax({ url: 'w.php5' ,
         data: { id: x },
         success: function(data) {
                   window.location.reload()
                }
 }); 
}
```

This is what I have and I've looked it over endless times for flaws, made sure the php variable is reading properly and made sure the function is truly being called. The php file works properly when called w.php5?id=1

Why won't this ajax call work?

Thanks in advance for the help, Aaron.

Comment: How are you calling `winA()` ?

Comment: onClick of a picture: <img src="<?=$img2src?>" width="250" name='right' onclick="winA();"/>

Comment: add error callback to your ajax call, if you debug it using developer tools, is the succes function launched? Is the path to w.php5 ok?

Comment: No, the success function doesn't get launched (the page is not reloaded) and the php does not execute (I can tell because it is meant to update a mySQL server

Comment: @AaronBoswell Hi again, are you sure `w.php5` exists and it interpretted by php, have you visited the script directly?

Comment: The path is OK, it is in the same folder as the file that I'm running.

Comment: then it is some php or path problem, add error callback(check jQuery documentation for that), also check error log if there is any error in php

Comment: If you're doing any MySQL work on `w.php5` make sure you're properly connecting to your database and the username has proper privileges.

Comment: This is where you use firebug or chrome developer tools.

Comment: w.php5 works when I access it directly via the URL

Comment: add this to your ajax call: 
                `error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }` and tell us if it is called and what is the result

Comment: okay, also i do have firebug it just doenst help at all

Comment: how firebug doesn't help? it'l show whether the ajax call has been made or not. it'l show you the variables and their values. and the response!

Comment: added the error, nothing happened

Comment: how does it indicate an ajax call has been made?

Comment: hmm .. is the winA() function even running? Is w.php5 called? Check using firebug or developer tools

Comment: firebug keeps telling me $ is not defined, any tips?

Comment: goto 'NET', then below click 'xhr' and then run the function 'winA'. if there's new entry in the list, it means call has been made. Then you have to see the response. if no new entry, it means you have error in the ajax call.

Comment: do you have jQuery on your page?

Comment: echo the $id normally in your page. it probably isn't defined.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
 i say that at the top of the page if that is what you mean

Comment: it says "$ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $.ajax({ "

Comment: where it says that? in the response? did the ajax call made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function winA() 
{
var x = "<?php echo $id;?>"
$.ajax({ url: 'w.php5' ,
         data: { id: x },
         success: function(data) {
                   window.location.reload()
                }
         error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
         { 
             alert(xhr.status); 
             alert(thrownError); 
         }
 }); 
}
```

This way it will show alert in case of ajax error

Also, if in chrome, press the combination Ctrl+Shift+I for developer tools and check network tab to see if w.php5 is called, and what is the response. Dont know tools for other browser but there should be something like that

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 alternatives.

**If you want to post some other data, use this**

```
.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:'w.php5',
  data: {id: '<?php echo $id; ?>'},
  success: function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
  },
  dataType:'json'
});
```

If you go this way, your ID is going to be stored in $_POST array => *$_POST['id']*

**If you want to just get some data by ID you post, use this**

```
.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url:'w.php5?id=<?php echo $id; ?>',
  success: function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
  },
  dataType:'json'
});
```

If you go this way, your ID is going to be stored in $_GET array => *$_GET['id']*

Comment: so? What's wrong with this code? Whoever downvoted it...
If you do *$id = $_GET['id']*, use second code sample. That sample uses GET method to "post" your ID to the php file requested in your AJAX call

Comment: is there anything you are required to load before using ajax? because my ajax request never seem to go through

Comment: also do u need to put a $ in front of a ajax call?

Comment: wouldnt advise using `datatype: 'json'` at this stage, it could actually couse the same problem in case php response is not json encoded - for example if his config allows showing errors and warning on page and there is some warning in php

Comment: try to add this after "success" callback function...

error: function(a,b){
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}

This will show you any error messages, if AJAX call fails.

One more question... What is the output of your PHP script?
I mean, when you access *w.php?id=1* for example. What is outputted  by this script to browser? There should be fome *echo* statement, for example...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon here:

```
var x = "<?php echo $id;?>"
```

Should be:

```
var x = "<?php echo $id;?>";
```

Comment: Right click your page, click view page source, and do you see `var x` actually being echoed by php?

Answer (score 0):

//set the method

POST or GET

```
type:'GET'; or type:"POST"
```

Comment: Default type is get anyways but ill give it a shot, could u show me exactly how to format that with my code above?

Comment: Add the line `type: 'POST',` (or GET) after the line `data: { id: x },`

Answer (score 0):

That url is probably missing a leading forward-slash, assuming you are trying to access a url like www.myurl.com/w.php?id=5

Try

```
url: '/w.php?id=5',
```

If that doesn't work, you need to inspect the request using a developing tool within Chrome or Firefox.

You can also var_dump the $_GET or $_POST in w.php, as the response will expose the output.